# Why does BeautifulSoup skip over some tables when using findAll

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the "Four Factors" table from the following URL, https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/201810160GSW.html, when I use the findAll method in the BeautifulSoup library when searching for tables I do not see that table, nor do I see the "Line Score" table. I am only concerned with the "Four Factors" table, but I figured the note about the "Line Score" table could be useful information.

```
URL2 = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/201810160GSW.html'
page2 = requests.get(URL2)
page2 = page2.text
soup2 = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page2, 'html.parser')
content = soup2.findAll('table')
```

If you look at content, you can find the other 4 tables on the page, but the "Four Factors" and "Line Score" do not show up there. In addition to helping me extract the "Four Factors" table, can you explain why it doesn't show up in content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It comes out in one of the comments which is why you weren't finding it I think.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup , Comment
import pandas as pd

r =requests.get('https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/201810160GSW.html')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')
comments= soup.find_all(string=lambda text:isinstance(text,Comment))

for comment in comments:
    if 'id="four_factors"' in comment:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(comment, 'lxml')
        break
table = soup.select_one('#four_factors')
df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0].fillna('')
print(df)
```